# How to map a value object identity in EF6 using fluent api?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-6, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-migrations

In DDD, it is a common design to make the identity of an entity be a value object.

Example:

```
public class FooId : ValueObject  
{  
    public int Id { get; private set; }
}  

public class Foo
{  
    public FooId FooId { get; private set; }
}
```

In EF6, I can map types like these using the code below:

```
modelBuilder.ComplexType<SomeType>()
    .Property(x => x.SomeProperty)
    ...
```

(see [3 Reasons to Model Identity as A Value Object](https://buildplease.com/pages/vo-ids/), [IDDD](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples))

> Edit: [IDDD in .Net](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples_NET)

But when I try to map Foo and FooId, I get the following error during migrations

> The properties expression 'x => x.FooId.Id' is not valid. The expression should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: C#: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) New With { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.

My Configurations:

```
public class FooConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{  
    public FooConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.FooId.Id);
    }
}  

public class FooContext : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{  
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ComplexType<FooId>();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FooConfiguration());
    }
}
```

Packages Used

- EntityFramework 6.2.0
- MySql.Data 6.10.7
- MySql.Data.Entity 6.10.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently it is not possible in `EF 6.x` and you have to deal with regular primitives. Though it is possible in `EF core 2.1` using [Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions).

As an alternative in classic `.Net Framework` you can try `NHibernate` since it allows to have value object as the identity. `NHibernate` still looks more powerful than `EF` from the `Domain-Driven Design` perspective.

Answer (score 1):

EF automatically recognizes complex types (value objects), you don't need to add any fluent api mappings.

I am giving you an example from [this course, by Julie Lerman](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/entity-framework-enterprise-update/table-of-contents)

`Address` is a ValueObject:

```
public class Address 
{
    public string Street { get; private set; }
    public string City { get; private set; }
    public string StateProvince { get; private set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; private set; }
}
```

`SalesOrder` is our entity, which is using `Address` complex type.

```
public class SalesOrder
{
    public int SalesOrderId { get; private set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; private set; }
    public string PurchaseOrderNumber { get; private set; }
    public string Comment { get; private set; }
    public Address ShippingAddress { get; private set; }
}
```

Now if you use EF code first to build your DB tables, this is what you will get (migration code):

```
CreateTable("SalesOrder", c => new
{
    SalesOrderId = c.Int(nullable: false),
    OrderDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
    DueDate = c.DateTime(),
    PurchaseOrderNumber = c.String(),
    Comment = c.String(),
    ShippingAddress_Street = c.String(),
    ShippingAddress_City = c.String(),
    ShippingAddress_StateProvince = c.String(),
    ShippingAddress_PostalCode = c.String(),
})
.PrimaryKey(t => t.SalesOrderId);
```

Note that EF directly added all the address field to the table.

You don't need any additional fluent api mappings to let entity framework to add `Address` fields to the table, the above is the default behavior.

This is how the `DbContext` looks like:

```
public class OrderContext: DbContext
{
    public OrderContext() : base("connectionStringName") { }
    DbSet<SalesOrder> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have lots of value objects in my project and yes I can properly map them with EF. The only thing I was trying to achieve was to also make use of a value object as an identity which, as stated by @Albert, is not currently supported in EF. I thought maybe there is a workaround that other people uses for it to work that’s why I posted this question here on SO. Right now I am still using primitives for my identities as moving to another ORM is a bit costly for me in my current project, maybe on my next one I’ll try what Albert suggested